# Java: Filling in a rectangle on a grid

Tags: java

I'd like to begin by saying this is an assignment.  I do not want the answer spoon fed to me but I would like to know what is causing my problems.

I am currently implementing Conway's Game of Life.  Clicking the cell should change the color, as to represent that cell being switched to an alive state.  if clicked again, it should return to the default color.

When I click anywhere in the window, the program throws a Null Pointer Exception at line 56.  Have been stuck on this for the last day or so, so any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Heres the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class VisibleGrid extends JPanel implements MouseListener, KeyListener{ 

  CellGrid cellGrid;
  Graphics rect;

  public VisibleGrid(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    cellGrid = new CellGrid();
  }

  //Draw the grid of cells, 7px wide, 75 times to create 75x75 grid
  public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(int i=0; i<525;i=i+7){
      for(int j = 0; j<525; j=j+7){
        g.drawRect(i ,j,7,7);       
      }
    }   
  }

  //auxillary method called to fill in rectangles
  public void paint(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    g.fillRect(x, y, 7, 7);
    repaint();

  }

  //main method, adds this JPanel to a JFrame and sets up the GUI  
  public static void main(String[] args){
    JFrame j = new JFrame("Conway's Game of Life");
    j.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    j.add(new VisibleGrid(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JTextArea info = new JTextArea("Press S to Start, E to End");
    info.setEditable(false);
    j.add(info, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    j.setSize(530,565);
    j.setVisible(true);
  }

  //these methods are to satisfy the compiler/interface
  //Begin Mouse Events
  public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    //fill the selected rectangle
    rect.fillRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), 7,7); 
    repaint();

    //set the corresponding cell in the grid to alive
    int row = e.getY() /7;
    int column = e.getX() /7;
     cellGrid.getCell(row, column).setAlive(true);
  } 
  //End Mouse Events

//These methods are to satisfy the compiler/interface
//Begin KeyEvents
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){}
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){}
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e){}



}
```

Comment: Which line is line 56? When I copy/pasted the code, it was int column = e.getX() /7; which doesn't look right

Comment: i bet line 56 is _rect.fillRect(e.getX(), e.getY(), 7,7);_

Comment: As @guido says, make sure that the graphics object, `rect` is initialized or have a valid reference, before accessing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that your `rect`  field is never set to anything so it stays as `null`.  Calling `rect.drawRect` will cause the NullPointerException you're seeing.

If I remember correctly, Swing `Graphics` objects don't really like you painting on them when they're not expecting you to be doing any painting.  I would therefore recommend against stashing the `Graphics` object you get during a call to `paint()` in a field such as `rect`.  If you want to repaint part of the window, it's better to tell Swing what part of the window needs repainting and then let it call your `paint()` method.

Within your `mouseClicked()` method, I removed the call to `rect.fillRect()` and moved the call to `repaint()` to the end of the method.  I also modified the `paint()` method to draw a filled rectangle if the cell was alive and an unfilled one otherwise.  After doing this, your code appeared to work, in that I could click on some cells and they would turn black.

I have a few suggestions for improvements to your code.  I'll leave the last two as exercises for you:

- I'd recommend adding the line `j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` to `main()`.  This line makes the application quit properly when you close the window.
- At the moment, your code is repainting the entire 75 × 75 grid every time a single cell changes.  It should be possible to change your code so that it repaints only the changed cell.  You can [pass a `Rectangle` to the repaint() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#repaint%28java.awt.Rectangle%29), which tells Swing 'only this part of my component needs to be repainted'.  In the `paint` method, you can get hold of this rectangle using [the `getClipBounds()` method of the `Graphics` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#getClipBounds%28%29) and use it to determine which cell or cells to repaint.
- `drawRect` only draws the outline of a rectangle.  If a cell dies, your `paint` method won't clear the existing black rectangle from the grid.  You could fix this by drawing dead cells as a white filled rectangle with a black outline rectangle on top.

Comment: Thank you so much for the very helpful answer! I now have an almost complete implementation of the game, I just need to finish the algorithm for the actual game, but the GUI part is done.  Thanks again, man.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the `CellGrid` objects has been filled with cells? I'm no Java expert but I don't see in your code this initialization...

Comment: Yes, the CellGrid object is filled with Cell objects in it's constructor.  I got the GUI portion of the program figured out just now.  Thanks!